# Macro to delete contents of cells using their references

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of references of cells to be deleted. The list of references is in sheet "test_url". The list of references point to cells to be deleted that are in another sheet "main_lists".

What I am after is a macro that takes all the references listed in "test_url" sheet, and select their cells in "main_lists" sheet and delete them.

The following macro is what I recorded for two references only in an attempt to demonstrate my problem that necessitated me to copy the reference from "test_url" sheet, then paste it in the NameBox of "main_urls" sheet to select the contents of the designated cell then delete its contents. This process was done manually one cell at a time for a list of 10-20 addresses/references. However, recently this list is over 2000 entries and it is growing:

```
Sub DeletePermittedCells()
'DeletePermittedCells Macro
Sheets("test_urls").Select
Range("B2").Select
Sheets("test_urls").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("main_lists").Select
Application.Goto Reference:="R200045C1"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("test_urls").Select
Range("B3").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("main_lists").Select
Application.Goto Reference:="R247138C1"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("test_urls").Select
End Sub
```

Can someone help with this issue please?

Comment: am I correctly understood, that your `test_urls` sheet contains (in column B) cells addresses of main_lists sheet that should be cleared (like `A1999`, `A123` and so on)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub DeletePermittedCells()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr, c

    With Sheets("test_urls")
        'storing data in array makes your code much faster
        arr = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

    With Sheets("main_lists")
        Set rng = .Range(arr(1, 1))
        For Each c In arr
            Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(c))
        Next
    End With

    rng.ClearContents
End Sub
```

storing addresses in array (rather than reading each cell from worksheet directly) makes your code *much faster*.

Note, code assumed that your addresses stored in range `B2:B & lastrow` where `lastrow` - is row of last cell with data in column `B`

Comment: Much obliged simoco, this is a and excellent code that really achieve the goal 100%. Thank you very much, this is the least I can say.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the list of cells to be cleared in is column **A**:

```
Sub ClearCells()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, I As Long, addy As String
    Set s1 = Sheets("test_url")
    Set s2 = Sheets("main_lists")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 1 To N
        addy = s1.Cells(I, 1).Value
        s2.Range(addy).ClearContents
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gary's Student for your sincere attempt to help with my question, highly appreciated.